# System ODBC does not appear when linking tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I have a a system ODBC pipe that connects to a SQL Server database.  Now, when I try to link tables in ACCESS, the system ODBC does not appear under the System tab.  If I open ODBC from the windows search and check, it's in there, but ACCESS can't seem to find it.  Windows 7 Pro, Office 2013.

Thanks

Comment: Has Access been upgraded at all? Ensure you're using the correct driver, either 32bit or 64bit, for the application.

Comment: I would avoid using system ODBC anyway. Create your connection Access. It is far less painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch Access x32 bits, then it will launch the x32 bit ODBC manger.

However, if you launch say the control panel in windows, then it will launch the x64 bit version of the ODBC manager.

So either from the windows command line ensure you launch the correct version of the ODBC manager. There are two editions, once is x32 bits, and the other is x64 bits.

However, most easy is to just let access launch the ODBC manager. If your connect is not listed, the simply re-crate it in the ODBC panel.

So your issue is very likely that you are launching the wrong bit size of the ODBC manager.

Most installs of Access are x32 bits, even on x64 bit windows. However, there is an x64 bit version of Access available – so check that.

But as noted, Access will correctly launch the correct version of the ODBC manager for you – so launch the odbc manager from Access and not say the control panel to ensure that the correct version (x32 or x64) of ODBC manager is launched.